# Python external merge sort running slowly

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, sorting, mergesort

I am a CS student (thus new to programming) and I am trying to implement an External Merge Sort algorithm in Python like [this one](https://github.com/melvilgit/external-Merge-Sort/blob/master/externalMergeSort.py).
The data to be sorted is a large CSV file with about 9.000.000 rows like that one:

```
1743-11-01,6.068,1.736,StadtA,Denmark,57.05N,10.33E
1744-06-01,5.787,3.623,StadtB,Belgien,47.05N,10.33E
```

So far, I have this function which seperates the csv file into multiple pre-sorted chunks:

```py
    def splitFiles(self, largeFileName, smallFileSize):
        largeFileHandler = csv.reader(open(largeFileName), delimiter=',')
        tempBuffer = []
        size = 0
        for row in largeFileHandler:
            tempBuffer.append(row)
            size += 1
            if (size % smallFileSize == 0):
                tempBuffer.sort(key=lambda x: (x[5], -float(x[1]), x[3]))
                tempFile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=self.cwd + '/temp', delete=False, mode="wb+")
                writer = csv.writer(tempFile)
                writer.writerows(tempBuffer)
                tempFile.seek(0)
                sortedTempFileHandlerList.append(tempFile)
                tempBuffer = []
```

This means the chunks get sorted descending by the fifth element. If that one is equal then sort increasing by first element and if that is also equal then sort by third element.

Everything works fine until there.
But merging these chunks into one (final) big file takes ages.

```py
    def merge(self):
        stack_tops = []
        sink = csv.writer(open("outputfile", "w+"))
        for f in sortedTempFileHandlerList:
            stack_tops.append(next(csv.reader(f)))

        while stack_tops:
            c = min(stack_tops, key=lambda x: (x[5], -float(x[1]), x[3]))
            sink.writerow(c)
            i = stack_tops.index(c)
            try:
                t = next(csv.reader(sortedTempFileHandlerList[i]))
                stack_tops[i] = t
            except StopIteration:
                del stack_tops[i]
                self.sortedTempFileHandlerList[i].close()
                del self.sortedTempFileHandlerList[i]
```

My question is, how am I able to make the second part run much faster?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you probably want to instantiate the readers once (are you sure it doesn't read the first values from each file repeatedly, also?). Also if you have tens of files a heap approach would be better than linearly scanning the stacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a spinning hard drive, the cause of your problem is likely excessive disk seeks.  If you are reading from dozens of files in parallel, the disk drive gives up and each read takes until the disk spins.  At 6000 rpm, that full rotation is 0-0.01 seconds, averaging 0.005 seconds.  200 reads per second adds up when your files have many megabytes of data between them.

The solution is to merge just a few files at a time.

How I have personally written this in the past is to keep a stack of objects which include `{file: ___, size: ___}`.  And then your logic looks like this:

```
while more to read:
    read a chunk
    write a sorted chunk
    add file info to stack
    while n < len(stack) and sum of sizes of top n-1 elements exceeds the nth:
        pop top n objects off of stack
        merge them
        push merged element onto stack

merge stack to get answer
```

You will have to play with it to figure out how many to merge.  But I successfully used this strategy for processing a dataset with billions of rows and it performed well.  I think I set `n` to 4.

(Complication in my real life example, due to disk limitations I had to keep all of my intermediate files compressed.  I was also merging and aggregating results as I went.  I would have preferred to do it in a database but the database ran out of room.  That was a fun project...)

---

More detail.

First of all, since this is Python, I would suggest that you make your `splitFiles` into an iterator.  Like this pseudocode:

```
 def splitFiles (inputFile):
     open inputFile
     create in memory data
     while more to read:
         add to data
         if data is full:
             write sorted temp file
             yield (fileSize, tempFile)
     if data:
         write sorted temp file
         yield (fileSize, tempFile)
```

Those `yield`s make it an iterator.  And now your main logic goes like this:

```
stack = []
for chunk in splitFile(dataFile):
    stack.append(chunk)
    while 3 < len(stack) and stack[-4][0] < sum((stack[-i][0] for i in [1, 2, 3])):
        chunks = []
        for _ in range(4):
            chunks.append(stack.pop())
        stack.append(mergeChunks(chunks))

# Now the final merge
while 1 < len(stack):
    chunks = []
    for _ in range(4):
        if len(stack):
            chunks.append(stack.pop())
        stack.append(mergeChunks(chunks))
return stack[0][1]
```

In the example you offer of 8 3MB chunks your stack would progress like this:

```
[]
[(3_000_000, tempFile1)]
[(3_000_000, tempFile1), (3_000_000, tempFile2)]
[(3_000_000, tempFile1), (3_000_000, tempFile2), (3_000_000, tempFile3)]
[(3_000_000, tempFile1), (3_000_000, tempFile2), (3_000_000, tempFile3), (3_000_000, tempFile4)]
# First merge!
[(12_000_000_000, tempFile5)]
[(12_000_000_000, tempFile5), (3_000_000, tempFile6)]
[(12_000_000_000, tempFile5), (3_000_000, tempFile6), (3_000_000, tempFile7)]
[(12_000_000_000, tempFile5), (3_000_000, tempFile6), (3_000_000, tempFile7), (3_000_000, tempFile8)]
[(12_000_000_000, tempFile5), (3_000_000, tempFile6), (3_000_000, tempFile7), (3_000_000, tempFile8), (3_000_000, tempFile9)]
# Second merge!
[(12_000_000_000, tempFile5), (12_000_000_000, tempFile10)]
# End of input, final merge
[(24_000_000_000, tempFile11)]
```

And the last file is your result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Let's say after splitting the input file, I've got 143 pre sorted chunks which all have the same size of 3MB. According to your algorithm the program would pick the first 3 elements (assuming n is 4) because n < 143 and 9MB > 3MB and then merges them the way I described it?

Comment: @ah3 No.  It would generate 4 chunks, realize that the 4th is not larger than the first 3 and merge 4 to get 1 big chunk.  It would then generate 4 more chunks and do the same so you have 2 big chunks. Then again.  And the 4th time through it would realize that it can merge and merge to get 1 really big chunk.  Then continue on.

Comment: This keeps the number of chunks small, interleaves merges and reading, and keeps the merges only of a fixed number of things.

Comment: Please have a look at my latest reply

Comment: @ah3 Sorry for not responding, I was doing Thanksgiving.  Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

@btilly Let's break this down a bit. After running the splitFiles method, I've got 8 chunks, each 3MB. The stack looks like that

```
[(tempfile1, 3), (tempfile2, 3), (tempfile3, 3), (tempfile4, 3), (tempfile5, 3), (tempfile6, 3), (tempfile7, 3), (tempfile8, 3)]
```

With n being 4 (which is lower than the length with 8) and the sum of sizes of top n-1 elements (9) being greater than the size of the nth (3) we head into the while loop.

The first 4 tempfiles get merged and the stack now looks like this:

```
[(merged_chunk, 9), (tempfile5, 3), (tempfile6, 3), (tempfile7, 3), (tempfile8, 3)]
```

n is still 4, length of stack is 5 and the sum of sizes of top n-1 elements (15) is greater than the size of the nth (3)

So merged_chunk gets merged with tempfile5, tempfile6 and tempfile7 leaving the stack as follows:

```
[(merged_chunk, 18), (tempfile8, 3)]
```

Now we're at the point where the while condition fails, because n is greater than the length of the stack.
At that point there would be one last merge of merged_chunk and tempfile8?

Comment: No.  You start merging during the `splitFiles` method.  I will add to my answer some more details.